# If the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}f_n \left(x \right)$ converges but not uniformly does the sequence $\left(f_n\left(x\right)\right)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

From Cauchy Criterion for Uniform Convergence we can conclude that
if the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}f_n \left(x \right)$ converges uniformly than the sequence $\left(f_n\left(x\right)\right)$ converges uniformly to $f\left(x\right)=0$.

But if the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}f_n \left(x \right)$  converges but not uniformly does it mean that the sequence $\left(f_n\left(x\right)\right)$ must also converge ?

I failed to prove this statement and failed to found counter-example of convergent but not uniformly convergent series with divergent sequence.

Could you please give me some hint ?

Thanks.

Comment: If a sum converges, it terms go to zero.

Comment: Of course ! Nice and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the series $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges pointwise, then the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to zero. To see this, fix the variable $x$. Then the question simply becomes one about sequences and series of numbers rather than sequences and series of functions.